# visual studio c++ how to properly use fopen() to open txt file

Tags: c, file, fopen, fs

I am learning c++ and the excersise involves opening a .txt file and reading from it.
The project structure is as following:
[image]

```
int main()
{

    static const char* full_name = "C:\Users\Lukas\Desktop\Programming\file_system_test\file_system_test\items.txt";
    FILE* my_file = fopen(full_name , "r");
    if (my_file == NULL) {
        perror("error opening file");
    }

}
```

I am trying to fopen items.txt but with no luck yet..
[image]

I am not exactly sure what is the problem since I provide the full path..

METHODS TRIED SO FAR:

1. **Using double backslash in full path**

```
static const char* full_name = "C:\\Users\\Lukas\Desktop\\Programming\\file_system_test\\file_system_test\\items.txt";
```

Error still persists with:
`error opening file: No such file or directory`

**SOLVED**

The only thing that seems to fix this code is to use raw string literal as following:

```
static const char* full_name3 = R"(C:/Users/Lukas/Desktop/Programming/file_system_test/file_system_test/items.txt)";
    FILE* my_file3 = fopen(full_name3, "r");
    if (my_file3 == NULL) {
        perror("error opening file");
    }
```

Does not return any errors anymore.

Comment: Do you know that you pass `fn` instead of `full_name` to `fopen`?

Comment: What is `fn` ? Your compiler should point this out even before allowing you to build this.

Comment: `fopen` takes filename as its first parameter

Comment: My bad. Just a typo. Now fixed. The code was run with the correct code so the output is as it should be.

Comment: Offtopic: code is C not C++ - so fix code or question tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note [escape sequences](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/escape) of string literals, so your path:

```c
static const char* full_name = "C:\Users\Lukas\Desktop\Programming\file_system_test\file_system_test\items.txt";
```

contains `\f` escape sequence which is interpreted as `form feed - new page     byte 0x0c in ASCII encoding`. This character can't be part of of a path so `Invalid argument` error is reported.

Also [compilers complain](https://godbolt.org/z/z6rzT1Txd) that other escape sequences are unknown.

There are three ways to fix it.

1. As `Luka Rahne` suggested by using back slash escape sequence `\\`
2. Or by using forward slashes (since `C` suppose to be portable, standard library is able to convert Unix path separator to platform specific path separators).

```c
static const char* full_name = "C:/Users/Lukas/Desktop/Programming/file_system_test/file_system_test/items.txt";
```

3. If you are using C++11 or newer (your code is C not C++, but tag says C++), you can leverage raw string literal:

```c
static const char* full_name = R"(C:\Users\Lukas\Desktop\Programming\file_system_test\file_system_test\items.txt)";
```

Here I did some live testing with msvc (file named: `open.c`):

```c
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, const char argv[])
{
#if VERSION == 0
    // here '\f' is used to reproduce error "invalid argument":
    static const char name[] = "C:\fUsers\\User\\Downloads\\open.c";
#elif VERSION == 1
    static const char name[] = "C:\\Users\\User\\Downloads\\open.c";
#elif VERSION == 2
    static const char name[] = "C:/Users/User/Downloads/open.c";
#elif VERSION == 3
    static const char name[] = R"(C:\Users\User\Downloads\open.c)";
#endif
    FILE* f = fopen(name, "r");
    
    if (!f) {
        perror("fopen");
        return 1;
    }
    
    char buf[256] = "";
    
    fgets(buf, sizeof(buf), f);
    printf("%s\n", buf);
    
    fclose(f);
    
    return 0;
}
```

Here is result of compiling and running from `cmd.exe`:

```sh
C:\Users\User\Downloads>cl open.c /D VERSION=0 && open.exe
Microsoft (R) C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 19.28.29336 for x86
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

open.c
Microsoft (R) Incremental Linker Version 14.28.29336.0
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

/out:open.exe
open.obj
fopen: Invalid argument

C:\Users\User\Downloads>cl open.c /D VERSION=1 && open.exe
Microsoft (R) C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 19.28.29336 for x86
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

open.c
Microsoft (R) Incremental Linker Version 14.28.29336.0
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

/out:open.exe
open.obj
#include <stdlib.h>


C:\Users\User\Downloads>cl open.c /D VERSION=2 && open.exe
Microsoft (R) C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 19.28.29336 for x86
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

open.c
Microsoft (R) Incremental Linker Version 14.28.29336.0
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

/out:open.exe
open.obj
#include <stdlib.h>


C:\Users\User\Downloads>cl open.c /D VERSION=3 && open.exe
Microsoft (R) C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 19.28.29336 for x86
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

open.c
open.c(11): warning C4129: 'm': unrecognized character escape sequence
open.c(11): warning C4129: 'D': unrecognized character escape sequence
open.c(11): warning C4129: 'o': unrecognized character escape sequence
open.c(11): error C2065: 'R': undeclared identifier
open.c(11): error C2143: syntax error: missing ';' before 'string'
open.c(11): error C2099: initializer is not a constant
```

So everything works as I described and last version `3` fails since I compile code as `C`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer and for pointing out what is the issue! However, Both 1 and 2 return the same error : ```error opening file: No such file or directory```.  How do you tell if its C? I am following a C++ guide and this is the excersise I am doing. I have created a c++ visual studio project and my source code is with cpp extension. Why is this not a c++ code?

Comment: I have made some progress by using your suggestion raw string literal. I have updated my initial post. It seems to be working only with 3. 1 and 2 not working

Comment: Now you have new problem. Error should be clear: file in that path doesn't exists. So either you have typo in that path or file was deleted.

Comment: I am able to sucesfully read the contents of the file using fgets so everything is correct. However, it only works when I use raw string literal. It does not work with 2 other methods that you have suggested even though the path is exactly the same. Could there be any other issues that prevent 1. and 2. from working?

Comment: @LukasPetrikas See edit, I've verified my answer on my machine and everything works as I described. If ot doesn't work for you, you still have some typo, which simply you do not see, or your build process is invalid (so you are testing old version of code).

Answer (score 0):

I believe your issue is that \ in filename is not properly escaped.
Your filename string should have double backslash characters.

```
static const char* full_name = "C:\\Users\\Lukas\\Desktop\\Programming\\file_system_test\\file_system_test\\items.txt";
```

You can test this, by sending this string trough std::cout for debug.

Comment: I have changed my full_name to : ```static const char* full_name = "C:\\Users\\Lukas\Desktop\\Programming\\file_system_test\\file_system_test\\items.txt"; ```. I am getting : ```error opening file: No such file or directory```