# Path of txt files in a Visual Studio project

Tags: path, txt

Good morning.

I have this simple exercise that ask me to read data from a txt file, elaborate it somehow and then write the result on another txt file.

I had a lot of problem making fopen to work (I'm asked to work in c89) and I have been able to solve them tanks to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67669631/visual-studio-c-how-to-properly-use-fopen-to-open-txt-file)

That said, my question is, how could I properly truncate that path.
I would like to have something inherent to the project structure Visual Studio made for me.
So, as in the image, I would like to put those txt files in Resources for example (or some other folder I add) and use them from there.

[image]

So instead of the complete path I must use:

C:\\Users\\[myname]\\Desktop\\[somefolder]\\doc\\input.txt

or

C:/Users/myname/Desktop/somefolder/doc/output.txt

in

```
static const char* nomefile = "C:\\Users\\myname\\Desktop\\somefolder\\doc\\input.txt";
.
.
fpIN = fopen (nomefile, "r");
```

I would like to pick those files in Resources, so something like

```
static const char* nomefile = ".\\Resources\\input.txt";
```

How can I do that?

Thanks